# Would it be right to ask my users to use a specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, etiquette

I'm planning on creating an online course on design for programmers (be it graphic, ui or web design). Would it fit the StackExchange etiquette to ask my users to use a specific tag to be able to filter out my "students"?

Here's an example: I have an assignment on creating a business card for yourself, if my student has a question on how to use bezier curves, I'd prefer him/her to head to Super User to leverage the power of "crowdsupporting" instead of handling it myself. This would allow me to focus on issues of design instead of issues of tools.

Still, I'd like to be able to lend them a hand whenever I can, so if I word things like...

"If you need help with Illustrator, head to superuser.com and use the tag "mywebsite", if I have the time I will answer your question. Otherwise, there's a lot of helpful people there that can help you with technical issues.

TL;DR Is it right to ask your users to use specific tags that are not useful to other SE regulars?

Comment: Downvoter: why? I'm asking before committing the crime!

Comment: On meta upvotes and downvotes on discussion questions are a measure of community agreement with your proposition. In this case, the downvote means that someone thought your idea was a bad one.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting idea, but I'd say no. Tags should be useful to all users, and most decidedly shouldn't be [meta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: Ah thanks, after reading Jeff's article it's very clear why this wouldn't be allowed. I agree on the reasoning and I'll consider my options (installing a SO clone or not being so parental with my users).